# How to pass array size to different functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters

I have a problem and it seems like I cannot find a proper answer that would do the trick... So I have this static array arr[some_number] and I want to have a menu which does things with that array. Of course 1 of the options is to fill the array. Everything should be in separate functions. Here is the first one:`

```
void fill_array(int arr[], const int size) {
int n;
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
 }
}
```

`

There should be the option to let the user input how much elements he wants for the array, obv. `n < some_number` in this case... but with this comes my question : How can I pass the variable `n` in this particular case to another function so it can illiterate the number of elements the user input but not the const size of the array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The C++ solution to most array problems is to use a `std::vector`. It can both grow and shrink when needed, and it knows its own size.

Comment: @rllstpwz  C++ does not support variable length arrays. You should use standard container std::vector.

Comment: I am not supposed to used vectors.

Comment: @rllstpwz  In this case there are two options. The first one is to allocate an array of the maximum expected size. The second one is to allocate an array dynamically and reallocate it when it is required.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, I just figured out that I could do the first option. It would do the trick since its about even less than 50 elements maximum expected size. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to separate responsibilities. A function like `fill_array()` has no business prompting the user for the array size at all. It already has a size value being passed in as input, just use that value as-is:

```
void fill_array(int arr[], const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
}
```

Prompt the user beforehand, and then pass the entered size to your functions as needed, eg:

```
int ask_user_for_size(int max_number)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a number between 1 - " << max_number << ": ";
        cin >> n;
        if ((n > 0) && (n <= max_number)) break;
        cout << "Invalid number, try again" << endl;
    }
    while (true);
    return n;
}

void fill_array(int arr[], const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
}

void output_array(const int arr[], const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i];
}

... 

int arr[some_number];
int n = ask_user_for_size(some_number);    
cout << "Enter " << n << " numbers: ";
fill_array(arr, n);
output_array(arr, n);
```

Alternatively:

```
int ask_user_for_size()
{
    int n;
    do
    {
           cout << "Enter a number greater than 0: ";
           cin >> n;
           if (n > 0) break;
           cout << "Invalid number, try again" << endl;
    }
    while (true);
    return n;
}

void fill_array(int *arr, const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
}

void output_array(const int *arr, const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i];
}

... 

int n = ask_user_for_size();
int *arr = new int[n];
cout << "Enter " << n << " numbers: ";
fill_array(arr, n);
output_array(arr, n);
delete[] arr;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I look through my question I think I didnt specify my problem quite well: I must use a static array and no pointers. Also lets say I have 2 functions . In the first I must choose how much elements I want to input, than input them  and in the second I want to output those elements but when I illiterate through the whole array const size if not every element has a value it just prints out a random 5 or 6 digit number.

Comment: This is why I want to pass the number of elements to another function so I can illiterate only through them but not the whole const size of the array which is in the beginning.